# How can I convert timestamp to datetime format in Dataprep?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataprep

I have this dataset that returns an `INT64` column with the info of date. In BigQuery I can use a `TIMESTAMP_SECONDS()` to have the info in datetime format but in Dataprep I do not have this option.

[This is my dataset and how I convert the INT64 in date format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjuNv.jpg)

[This is the normal procedure to convert it in Dataprep](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxMUv.jpg)

[This is the format that bigquery return me, so I tried this one and several others](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWFXn.jpg)

[And, this is how dataprep return the data, as a lot of errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VS5w.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You get an error because Dataprep expects values in Datetime, not Unix Timestamp.

To format Unix Timestamp into Datetime, you need use the function [`unixtimeformat()`](https://docs.trifacta.com/display/DP/UNIXTIMEFORMAT+Function).

The function accepts a 13-digit timestamp (in milliseconds). If your dataset has a timestamp below the digit, you must multiply it first accordingly. You can use another function called `multiply()` to create a new column. I'm using a 10-digit timestamp as sample dataset, so I multiplied it by `1000` so it becomes 13-digit.

Functions used:

```
MULTIPLY(column1, 1000) #creates column2

UNIXTIMEFORMAT(column2, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS") #creates finish_date
```

Sample Illustration:

[image]